# Subclipse not working after Apple Migration Assistent

Tags: eclipse, macos, subclipse

I had a laptop that developed hardware issues.  I used the Migration Assistant to transfer my files, etc over to the new laptop I got.

I discovered that Subclipse keeps throwing errors about JavaHL not being installed.  But when I try running

```
brew install --universal --java subversion
```

I get an error stating that

> Warning: subversion-1.8.10_1 already installed

So how do I fix this problem and get Subclipse working again?  I'm using Eclipse Indigo, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to select the pure Java client (see image below).  I don't believe the native client is available for OS X.  Also, I've never had to install anything at the command-line to use Subclipse.  The needed components are either part of the OS install or part of Subclipse.

That said, I've gotten myself into situations before where Subclipse just refused to work.  The fastest solution was just to reinstall eclipse and all the plugins.

[image]

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks!